# difference between += and append in python nested list concatenating

Tags: python, list, tuples, concatenation

for example:

```
re=[]
for i in range(5):
    #fill code here
```

- 1.) if we do "`re.append(i)`", re will be `[0,1,2,3,4]`
- 2.) if we do "`re.append([i])`", re will be`[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]`
- 3.) if we do "`re+=[i]`", re will be `[0,1,2,3,4]`
- 4.) if we do "`re+=[i],`", yes, with a trailing comma, and re will be `[[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]`

my question is, what does the comma do in #4 ? I always thought a trailing comma will make them into tuples, but they are lists apparently. So I also tried "`re+=i,`", and re will still be the list: `[0,1,2,3,4]`

then I did another try with the following:

```
re=[]
re=re+[1]
```

and now `re=[1]`
if I do:

```
re=[]
re=re+[1],
```

then `re=([1],)`, and re now is a tuple, no longer a list

and finally if I do:

```
re=[]
for i in range(5):
    re=re+[i]
```

re is now `[0,1,2,3,4]`

but if I changed it to:

```
re=[]
for i in range(5):
    re=re+[i],
```

now I get: `TypeError: can only concatenante tuple (not "list") to tuple`

Could anyone explain it to me what's going on here ? I tried googling for answers, but no one seems to talk about this

Comment: The comma creates a tuple.

Comment: `list.__iadd__` needs a sequence on the right hand side. By adding the comma you created a `tuple` with a single value, which extended the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[i],` is equivalent to `([i],)`, which is a tuple with one element, and that element is the list `[i]`.

When you concatenate any sequence to a list with `+=`, it iterates over the sequence and appends each element to the list. So

```
re += [i],
```

is equivalent to

```
for x in ([i],):
    re.append(x)
```

Since there's only one element in `([i],)`, this is further equivalent to:

```
re.append([i])
```

which is what you have in #2, so you get the same result.

Comment: so "re=re+[i], " is different fom "re+=[i]," ? i get TypeError from "re=re+[i],"

Comment: It's because of operator precedence. `re = re + [i],` is equivalent to `re = ((re + [i]),)` not `re = re + ([i],)`

Comment: now i get it, the 1st loop of "re=re+[i], " will make re a tuple ([0],), on the 2nd loop [1] cannot add to tuple because it's a list. And "+=" on the other hand does not add the whole thing, but iterate the whole seq and append each element. I didn't know the difference til today, thanks a ton, you just cleared my mind

Comment: It helps to add print statements to the loop to see what's going on.

Comment: I did, thats why i noticed "re+[i,]" is actually ((re+[0]),), i thought it'd be re+([0],)